# sql insert values into specific column

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm trying to insert a `nvarchar` value into a specific column in a table.  The value can possibly have reserved words and single quote chars(as in don't).

what I have is:

```
set @myString= REPLACE(@myString, '''', '''''');
set @ExecStatement = 'INSERT INTO #TempTable('+@ColumnName+') VALUES('''+@myString+''')';
exec (@ExecStatement)
```

This works for the vast majority of items but I get this error message:

> Msg 105, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Unclosed quotation mark after the character string 'We didn't understand, please resend, or type HE'.
>   Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near 'We didn't understand, please resend, or type HE'.

and I'm actually missing the remainder of the text that's supposed to be there. It's supposed to be `"We didn't understand, please resend, or type HELP and someone will contact you"`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should escape single quotes out of your input.

Comment: Since you are properly escaping the string, it should work.  Is there a trigger on the table that is using dynamic SQL?

Comment: Can you do a `SELECT @ExecStatement` before the `exec (@ExecStatement)` and show us what the result is?

Comment: Perhaps the problem is the length of the strings.  Can you show the `declare` statement.

Comment: @Tom  here's the select results:  `INSERT INTO #TempTable(Col1) VALUES('We didn''t understand, please resend, or type HELP and someone will contact you.')`

Comment: @GordonLinoff  the length of the nvarchars is max

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comment that your output string is:

```
INSERT INTO #TempTable(Col1) VALUES('We didn''t understand, please resend, or type HELP and someone will contact you.')
```

You will need to escape the quotes surrounding the string, and quadruple quote the ones that should actually be quotes...  Something like

```
INSERT INTO #TempTable(Col1) VALUES(''We didn''''t understand, please resend, or type HELP and someone will contact you.'')
```

Comment: meaning `set @myString= REPLACE(@myString, '''', '''''');`  would actually be `set @myString= REPLACE(@myString, '''', '''''''''');`?

Comment: Keep the `REPLACE` on `@myString` the same, but then do the same thing on `@ExecStatement`

Comment: So doing the `REPLACE` ON THE `@ExecStatement` did some funny things, so I just did `set @myString= REPLACE(@myString, '''', '''''''''');`  and that resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Using square brackets may help:

```
set @myString= REPLACE(@myString, '''', '''''');
set @ExecStatement = 'INSERT INTO #TempTable(['+@ColumnName+']) VALUES('''+@myString+''')';
exec (@ExecStatement)
```

Comment: the column name isn't the problem I'm having, it's the `@myString` that's giving me issues.

Comment: @shadonar . . . Somehow, you may know that.  However, we don't.  It would be helpful if you edited the question to include the value of `@ExecStatement` after the variable substitution.  Or at least the value of `@ColumnName`.

Comment: Maybe try  VALUES('N''